# Refreshing deep routes with Angular served by WebSphere Liberty

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

I'm working on creating a new Angular 4 website which is to be compiled into a WAR and hosted on an instance of WebSphere Liberty. To get it started, I'm simply packaging the Tour of Heroes demo app. Everything appears to work, until I hit refresh.

The WAR is at context path `game` and the `base href` is `""`, so that the stylesheets and scripts are always found as peers to the index.html file. The routes set up in `app-routes.module.ts` are the standard ones for the demo app:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
    { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent }
];
```

So visiting `localhost:8080/game` is correctly redirecting to `localhost:8080/game/dashboard`

Initially, it was giving a 404, so I added a web.xml with an error-page declaration:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>
```

And it works! But only on the dashboard, and only the first time. I notice that my URL in my browser becomes `localhost:8080/dashboard/dashboard`. Hitting refresh again causes a blank page to appear, and in the console. Moreover, refreshing from any other page redirects me to the dashboard, but also keeps my URL, whatever it may be. So `localhost:8080/game/heroes` becomes `localhost:8080/game/heroes/dashboard` and the dashboard shows up. Refreshing immediately again breaks things. I would expect at least to be taken to `localhost:8080/game/dashboard` although eventually I want refresh to work fully, taking me to the exact URL I was at before I refreshed.

It makes sense, based on those routes, that / would always go to dashboard, but why is my URL getting concatenated? What am I missing to get this set up correctly and navigating back to the right path on refresh? Is it the redirect that's the problem? Or the routing?

Comment: I managed to work around this. I set the base-href to "/" and adjusted my build to enforce "/" as the context root for the war. Refreshing works as I would expect, always bringing me back to the same page. Unfortunately I do not know if it is possible to have refreshing work in a context-root-agnostic way.